# window re-sizing using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've coded a GUI based Othello game. Am having a bit trouble re-sizing the game board. here is the code I have so far:

```
BOXWIDTH=60
BOXHEIGHT=60

class player:
"""Make a user player to play the game via a GUI."""

 def __init__(self,row,column):
    # create the GUI state variables
    self.alive = True
    self.move = None
    self.move_played = False
    # create the GUI windows and handlers
    self.root = tkinter.Tk()
    self.root.wm_title('Othello')
    self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)
    # create a button to get the No move command from the user
    tkinter.Button(self.root, text="No Move", command = self.nomove).pack()
    # create a label for displaying the next player's name
    self.movemesg = tkinter.StringVar()
    tkinter.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.movemesg).pack()
    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.root, bg="darkgreen",
                                height = BOXHEIGHT*row,
                                width = BOXWIDTH*column)

    self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)
    # create a box for highlighting the last move
    self.lastbox = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, BOXWIDTH*column,
                                                BOXHEIGHT*row,
                                                outline="red")
    # draw the game canvas
    for i in range(1,row):
        # horizontal lines
        self.canvas.create_line(0, i*BOXHEIGHT,
                               BOXWIDTH*column, i*BOXHEIGHT)
    for i in range(1,column):
        # vertical lines
        self.canvas.create_line(i*BOXWIDTH, 0,
                               i*BOXWIDTH, BOXHEIGHT*row)                                
    # the board will store the widgets to be displayed in each square
    self.board = [[None for y in range(row)]
                  for x in range(column)]
    # display the window
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.canvas.focus_set()
    self.root.update()

def draw_board(self, game, last_move):
    """Draw an othello game on the board."""
    ws = str(sum(x.count(1) for x in game.board))
    bs = str(sum(x.count(-1) for x in game.board))
    if game.player == -1:
        self.movemesg.set("Black to play  "+'\nSCORE: White = '+ws+'  Black = ' + bs)
    else:
        self.movemesg.set("White to play  "+'\nSCORE: White = '+ws+'  Black = ' + bs)

    for i in range(game.column):
        for j in range(game.row):
            color = game.get_color((i,j))
            if color == -1:
                board_color = "black"
            elif color == 1:
                board_color = "white"
            else:
                if self.board[i][j] is not None:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.board[i][j])
                    self.board[i][j] = None
                continue

            if self.board[i][j] is None:
                self.board[i][j] = self.canvas.create_oval(
                    i*BOXWIDTH+2, j*BOXHEIGHT+2, (i+1)*BOXWIDTH-2,
                    (j+1)*BOXHEIGHT-2, fill = board_color)
            else:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.board[i][j], fill=board_color)
```

I want the game board to resize i.e it must cause the area in which the board is drawn to change size correspondingly, with the game board redrawn to fill the available space. Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that the canvas wasn't told to grow when the main window grows. Change your pack statement to this:

```
self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Next, you will need to create a binding that gets called whenever the canvas resizes. You can do this by binding to `<Configure>`. For example:

```
self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_configure)
```

Finally, you will need to create a function that does nothing except redraw the board. You will call this method from the `on_configure` method.

Comment: for the last bit, the on_configure can I just call the draw_board function?

Comment: @user3233949: not as it's written -- your `draw_board` function seems to be drawing more than just the board. You actually draw the board in your `__init__` method. You should take that code out and put it in a method, and then call that method both from `__init__` and from the redraw function.